# Windows server 2008 r2 - Error listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, node.js, port-80

The website is deployed in windows server, the server is used to run the application is Node.js server, while running the website it gives this error

> ERROR listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

is there any change has to be made in the node.js server or Windows server.

Note: I already create a rule in windows server firewall at INBOUND RULES to allow Port :80 to access the website but it gives the error.

the above inbound rule is created with reference i got from Google.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have something already listening on port 80? Use `netstat` to list what programs are listening on what ports:

```
netstat -anb
```

Comment: sorry, i deployed the application in **windows server** please help me.

Comment: netstat works on windows and will tell you what is listening on port 80. Try binding to a different port and see if that works

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that IIS was listening on port 80. Simply visiting http://localhost shows the blue landing page for Internet Information Services.